# Newtonsoft Schema: .NET Core: Resolve schemas in private Azure Blob Container

Tags: authentication, json.net, authorization, schema, azure-blob-storage

**Context:**
I have an Azure Storage Account with a private blob container. In this container I have a root schema stored together with child schemas that are referenced by the root schema.

**Goal:**
My goal is to access the schemas in the private container and resolve them using JSchemaUrlResolver from Newtonsoft JSON.NET Schema and an identity (user identity / managed identity).

**Problem:**
I can't use SAS URIs. I.e. I have to use the "normal" Blob URI without any additional parameters. In my .NET Core application I can retrieve an Azure Credential and in this context also a token. But JSchemaUrlResolver only supports System.Net ICredential with Basic auth and I don't see an option to use the token respectively the Azure Credential to authenticate.

**Question:**
Is there a way (except for downloading the file e.g. using the SDK) to get and resolve the schemas stored in the private Blob container given the context described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement your own `JSchemaResolver` that is able to download files from your blob storage account.

See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/e00fb27edd710a4e4270c08b607143d15bc67c84/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/JSchemaUrlResolver.cs for an example of how a `JSchemaResolver` is implemented.